# How to delete blank rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro inherited from my coworker who left.

I have a sheet created from a source sheet, consisting of 30000 rows. Including the main data, over a million blank rows are created.

There are no blank rows between. It is 30k+ rows of data without a break.

I made a separate macro that deletes the blank rows after the fact.

I have to run the macro twice.
The first time, the black borders (carried over from the first sheet) are deleted, leaving a million borderless rows.
I run it a second time, which leaves the last used cell.

```vb
Sub DeleteUnused()
    
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myLastCol As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim dummyRng As Range
    
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wks
            myLastRow = 0
            myLastCol = 0
            Set dummyRng = .UsedRange
            On Error Resume Next
            myLastRow = _
              .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, _
              searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
              searchorder:=xlByRows).Row
            myLastCol = _
              .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, _
              searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
              searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column
            On Error GoTo 0
    
            If myLastRow * myLastCol = 0 Then
                .Columns.Delete
            Else
                .Range(.Cells(myLastRow + 1, 1), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
                .Range(.Cells(1, myLastCol + 1), _
                .Cells(1, .Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next wks
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this macro delete rows one by one, or a bunch at once?

Comment: I have an idea that will delete all blank rows in one go, but I need to re-create the excel sheet structure that you are having in my machine. Is it safe to assume that your sheet has hundreds of rows of data, but in between them are tens of blank rows? Is that the case?

Comment: Try this...`Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: If you had provided your code that crates the extra rows, it could have been fixed to not add the extra rows.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Ahmad, there are no blank rows between. It 30k+ rows of data without a break.

Comment: Thank you, GMalc. I will try this.

Comment: You could start a new question, with the code that adds the blank rows, and explain that it is inserting blank rows constantly. I'm sure someone would quickly identify what the problem is. It could be that you are either selecting all the rows down to the last row in the worksheet, or you are trying to find a value and then insert a row from the top-down, when you need to insert it bottom-up.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment this will delete blank rows. Just put this as the last line of the macro that created the blank rows.

```
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: This will remove entire rows if column A is empty. But what if that row has a value in column B?

Comment: @Ahmad the OP said that the macro used was was adding a million blank rows and he wanted to delete them. If that is not the case, he needs edit and clarify his question. I chose column A because most people have data in column A.  This code is the easiest way to remove blank rows that have been added to a spreadsheet due to a poorly written macro. As I commented, If the OP provides the original macro, it would have been easy fix so it didn't add the blank rows.

Comment: No, you are correct GMalc. 30k rows of data, followed by a million blank rows. I can provide the original macro now, if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the macro I use to clean-up all blank rows as well as blank columns.

You can decide if you only want to remove empty rows, and keep empty columns.

```
Sub Remove_Empty_Rows_And_Columns()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Dim row_rng As Range   'All empty rows will be collected here
    Dim col_rng As Range   'All empty columns will be collected here

    Dim last_row As Long    'points to the last row in the used range
    Dim last_column As Long 'points to the last column in the used range

    Dim i As Long           'iterator

    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    With wks

        'finding last row in used range
        last_row = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'finding last column
        last_column = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

        'loop through all rows in the used range and
        'find if current row is blank or not
        For i = 1 To last_row
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
                'current row is blank..

                If row_rng Is Nothing Then
                    'this is the first blank row. Lets create a new range for it
                    Set row_rng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    'this is not the first. Let's add it to the previous others
                    Set row_rng = Excel.Union(row_rng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next


        'same logic applies for empty rows
        For i = 1 To last_column
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(i)) = 0 Then
                If col_rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set col_rng = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set col_rng = Excel.Union(col_rng, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If

        Next

    End With


    'lets check if we managed to find any blank rows
    If Not row_rng Is Nothing Then
        row_rng.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "no rows to delete"
    End If


    'checking if we found any empty columns
    If Not col_rng Is Nothing Then
       col_rng.EntireColumn.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "no columns to delete"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Ahmad. I will give this a try.